# slick getting autoincrement id

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

is there a way to get right after inserting data via slick the autoincrement ID of this dataset?

```
val result: Future[Option[ProcessTemplatesModel]] = db.run(p).map(id => {
  Some(process)
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get autoincrement id after insertion,  you can use the following code from the slick documentation

> val userId =   (users returning users.map(_.id)) += User(None,
>   "Stefan", "Zeiger")